# PHP - Receive Json (POST)

Tags: php, android, json

I am sending a Json array to server :

```
{
"Name":"Number",
"Name":"Number" 
, ...
}
```

How can i receive it on PHP ?

Send method is POST .

Here is my android code :

```
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.7/admina/contacts_inout.php");

        String json = "";

        json = jsons.toString();

        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

        httpPost.setEntity(se);

        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
```

Comment: You can read raw post (since you aren't posting a form field)  using [php://input](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input).  A simple use/case would be `if(getenv('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST') { $data = file_get_contents("php://input"); }`

Comment: @KraangPrime Are you mean : file_get_contents("php://input"); ?

Comment: Yes.   Please read the edit to my last statement (and time last modified)

Answer (score 3):

Since PHP only handles POST-data which is application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data formatted, you'll have to use the RAW input

use

```
$sent_array = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
```

to get the data as an array

Answer (score 1):

```
isset($_POST['your_param_key']) or exit('param not found.');

$json = $_POST['your_param_key'];

$array = json_decode($json, true);

print_r($array);
```